Postgresql sum matching id quantity and delete duplicate rows
I have a table with a id, item_id and qty(quantity) column. I want to "merge/combine" the rows that match on the item_id. When I do this I want to SUM the qty per item_id update one row and remove the other rows. I found this solution but I was hoping for a single transaction solution(should I just put it in a procedure or function?). I was looking at the MERGE function but I was not able to figure out how to run both a update and a delete when we had a match, it also appeared to me that it was for merging two tables. I am sure there has to be a way to do it, it just seems to be outside my grasp.
Original dataset

The transaction method taken from the previous link.
UPDATE test t
SET qty = s.qty
FROM (SELECT MIN(id) id, SUM(qty) qty
 FROM test
 GROUP BY item_id) s
 WHERE s.id = t.id

DELETE FROM test t1
WHERE t1.id > (SELECT MIN(t2.id)
           FROM test t2
          WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id)

Results after the first transaction.

Results after the 2nd and final transaction. This is a result I am happy with.


Your results do not match your data.
Also, do not post screenshots here.
You can use an update/returning CTE to achieve this in one statement:
with newrecs as (
  select item_id, min(id) as id, sum(qty) as qty
    from test
   group by item_id
), updates as (
  update test t
     set qty = n.qty
    from newrecs n
   where (n.id, n.item_id) = (t.id, t.item_id)
  returning t.id
)
delete from test where id not in (select id from updates);

Working fiddle

Thanks! Not sure that I follow "Your results do not match your data." What's the preferred method to show table data? Type it in a code section?

@cxpcxd  The inventory values in your sample data do not sum to the amounts that you show in your desired output.  For table data, please paste your data in as text.  You can use markdown to use fixed-pitch formatting.
